# OpenJDK Server VM and unresolved dependencies warning when trying to add spark dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am getting the following error while adding spark-dependencies:

```
Error while importing sbt project:

OpenJDK Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
```

and

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;1.6.1: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming_2.12;1.6.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:1.6.1 (/home/chiralcarbon/IdeaProjects/pleasework/build.sbt#L8-12)
[warn]        +- default:pleasework_2.12:0.1
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.12:1.6.1 (/home/chiralcarbon/IdeaProjects/pleasework/build.sbt#L8-12)
[warn]        +- default:pleasework_2.12:0.1
```

This is the build.sbt file:

```
 name := "pleasework"

    version := "0.1"

    scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
    val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
    )
```

How to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark has not been released for Scala 2.12 yet. You need to use Scala 2.11 (I think 2.11.11 is the latest release) and spark-core_2.11 (SBT adds the "_2.11" suffix for you when you use the `%%` operator, that's why your compiler warns about not being able to find 'spark-core_2.12'). In general, you can usually find what the latest version of a Java or Scala library by checking the [Maven Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspark-core_2.11).